# How can I set default authorizer for all function in serverless.yml

Tags: lambda, serverless-framework, aws-policies

I have a problem with policy size of jwt authorizer lambda function so I want to reduce policy size by config serverless.yml file to generate policy using wildcard(*) instead. Can I set global authorizer for all functions in serverless.yml.

Here is my example of Resource-based policy

```
 {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1-jwtAuthorizer",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-1-abcdefg123"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1-jwtAuthorizer",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-1-abcdefg456"
        }
      }
    },
```

I want to change it like this.

```
{
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1-jwtAuthorizer",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-1-*"
        }
      }
    }
```

Example of serverless.yml file.
I set authorizer for each function.
I want to change it to global one.

```
functions:
  searchByProvince:
    handler: handler.searchByProvince
    reservedConcurrency: 10
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: "*"
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:lambda:${self:provider.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:jwtAuthorizer

  province:
    handler: handler.province
    reservedConcurrency: 10
    events:
      - http:
          path: /provinces
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: "*"
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:lambda:${self:provider.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:-${self:provider.stage}-jwtAuthorizer
```